# 18.04 boots ok, but once lock screen appears I can't unlock it

Tags: boot, gnome, gnome-screensaver

Started yesterday; the system is running all the background applications it is supposed to but the only way to use it interactively is to power off completely and restart. The screen, keyboard and mouse then operate fine but if I go away for 10 minutes and the screen sleeps I can't get past the lock screen. Normally the ESC key or a mouse click will prompt for a login, but not any more.

Looking in syslog there is a truckload of gdm-x-session and gnome-shell errors. I don't know if this is relevant but the first of these after reboot is as follows:

```
dbus-daemon[1086]: [session uid=125 pid=1086] Activating service name='org.gnome.ScreenSaver' requested by ':1:12' (uid=125 pid=1088 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --auto" label="unconfined")
org.gnome.ScreenSaver[1086]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
gnome-screensav[1094]: Cannot open display:
dbus-daemon[1086]: [session uid=125 pid=1086] Activated service 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' failed: Process org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1
gnome-session[1088]: gnome-session-binary[1088]: CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreenSaver: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.ScreenSaver: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1
```

and so on.

At the point when I try to reawaken the desktop this message is written to the log:

```
gnome-shell[1497]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: activate: Error: Error invoking IBus.set_global_engine_async: Expected function for callback argument callback, got undefined
```

Any suggestions where/how I could find out what is going wrong, and fix it?!

Thanks, T